# How to reduce manufacturing changeovers in job scheduling using Linear Programming in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am attempting to build a linear program (*pulp* using Python) to automatically schedule production jobs.  I have sample sales orders (order_book) and hour by hour capacity.

TLDR: Need help reducing changeovers by either adding a constraint to limit them or by adding a penalty to the objective function to incentive the model to do less of them.

I am currently attempting to produce all of demand (given capacity) and reduce changeovers.  I can successfully manipulate the constraints and objective functions to achieve other results, but I have been extremely unsuccessful in limiting changeovers. I want to just add a penalty for every time a SKU is produced after another SKU.
Sample sales orders below. Please ignore due dates and priorities at this point.

```
SKU Quantities  Due_Dates   Priority
0   SKU1    60000   2023-06-17 23:00:00 1
1   SKU2    30000   2023-06-17 23:00:00 1
2   SKU3    30000   2023-06-17 23:00:00 1
```

Sample Capacity Dataset below. For purposes of this, each hour has 1,000 units of capacity and I have 5 days (120 hours of capacity).

```
StartTime   Capacity    DateTime
0   6/15/2023 0:00  1000    2023-06-15 00:00:00
1   6/15/2023 1:00  1000    2023-06-15 01:00:00
2   6/15/2023 2:00  1000    2023-06-15 02:00:00
3   6/15/2023 3:00  1000    2023-06-15 03:00:00
4   6/15/2023 4:00  1000    2023-06-15 04:00:00
```

My code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
from pulp import LpMinimize, LpBinary, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable,value
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

order_book = pd.read_csv('./Formation Scheduler Test/order_book.csv')  # SKU, Quantities, Due_Dates, Priority
order_book['Due_Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(order_book['Due_Dates'])  # Ensure Due_Dates is datetime

order_book = order_book.sort_values(by=['Due_Dates','Priority'])
order_book = order_book.reset_index(drop=True)
display(order_book)

capacity_data = pd.read_csv('./Formation Scheduler Test/capacity_data.csv')  # Capacity per hour for next x days
capacity_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(capacity_data['StartTime'])
capacity_data = capacity_data.sort_values(by=['DateTime']) 
capacity_data = capacity_data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Pulp Code below

```
prob = LpProblem("Production_Scheduling", LpMinimize)

x = LpVariable.dicts("production", ((i, j) for i in order_book.index for j in capacity_data.index), lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
y = LpVariable.dicts("is_producing", ((i, j) for i in order_book.index for j in capacity_data.index), cat='Binary')
z = LpVariable.dicts("changeover", ((i, j) for i in order_book.index for j in range(len(capacity_data.index) - 1)), cat='Binary')

prob += lpSum([y[(i, j)] - y[(i, j+1)] for i in order_book.index for j in range(len(capacity_data.index) - 1)]) 

# Production cannot exceed capacity
for j in capacity_data.index:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i, j)] for i in order_book.index]) <= capacity_data.loc[j, 'Capacity']

    
for i in order_book.index:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i, j)] for j in capacity_data.index]) >= 360

    
# Production must meet demand
# for i in order_book.index:
#     prob += lpSum([x[(i, j)] for j in capacity_data.index]) >= order_book.loc[i, 'Quantities']
for i in order_book.index:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i, j)] for j in capacity_data.index]) <= order_book.loc[i, 'Quantities']

for i in order_book.index:
    prob += lpSum([x[(i, j)] for j in capacity_data.index]) >= lpSum([order_book.loc[i, 'Quantities'] * y[(i, j)] for j in capacity_data.index])

    
# Link x and y variables
for i in order_book.index:
    for j in capacity_data.index:
        prob += x[(i, j)] <= y[(i, j)] * large_number  # If y[i, j] is 0, then x[i, j] must also be 0

# Add changeover constraints
for i in order_book.index:
    for j in range(len(capacity_data.index) - 1):
        prob += z[(i, j)] >= y[(i, j)] - y[(i, j+1)]
        prob += z[(i, j)] >= y[(i, j+1)] - y[(i, j)]

prob.solve()
```

To view the results:

```
for i in order_book.index:
    for j in capacity_data.index:
        if y[(i, j)].varValue > 0:
            print(f"Produce {x[(i, j)].varValue} units of SKU {i} in hour {j}")
```

or you can do this to get a DF:

```
**# Prepare schedule and order status dataframes
schedule = []
order_status = []

for i in order_book.index:
    order_produced = 0
    order_late = 0  # Track late quantities
    for j in capacity_data.index:
        if x[(i,j)].varValue > 0:
            schedule.append([capacity_data.loc[j, 'DateTime'], order_book.loc[i, 'SKU'], x[(i, j)].varValue])
            order_produced += x[(i,j)].varValue
            if capacity_data.loc[j, 'DateTime'] > order_book.loc[i, 'Due_Dates']:
                order_late += x[(i,j)].varValue 
        
    order_status.append([
        order_book.loc[i, 'SKU'],
        order_book.loc[i, 'Quantities'],
        order_produced,
        order_late,
        max(0, order_book.loc[i, 'Quantities'] - order_produced),
        x,
        order_book.loc[i, 'Due_Dates']  # Add the original due date
    ])



schedule_df = pd.DataFrame(schedule, columns=['DateTime', 'SKU', 'Quantity'])**
```

Comment: this is difficult to advise on because it is completely non-reproducible.  `order_book.index` ??  etc.  My advice:  (1) ditch all of the `pandas` stuff and make an example that works with a couple of dictionaries that you include in the example, (2) then more clearly explain what your core issue is... How do you define a changeover?  If the plan is to make 500 SKU1 and 500 SKU2 in the first period and 400 SKU1 and 400 SKU2 in period 2, has a changeover occurred? and (3) put some effort into commenting your `pulp` code with intention of the variables and constraints.  It is confusing.

Comment: @AirSquid - I posted tables of the two csv files the pan Ada’s are reading. The order_book as well as the capacity Rata set sample. 

A single hour should only be able to procure one sku (a different constraint for a different time). A changeover occurs when a sku made in time t is not the same sku made in time t-1. Some changeovers are necessary. For example, once you make all of skU 1 you must proceed to make sku 2. 

However, the current solution appears random. Hours 1-3 will be SKU 1, hours 4-5 SKU 2 and hours 6-10 SKU 3 before making sku 1 again in hours 11-20.  (Ex for illustration)

Comment: expected result would help a lot

Comment: `Pre-processing says infeasible or unbounded`

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same optimization problem as you posted but the fundamental principle of the below problem is applicable to your use case.

To punish switching between articles at every time slot we construct a decision variable for every possible switch at every possible timestep and the n attach a cost to each possible switch. In particular, we're also allowed to keep producing the same article by switching from an article to itself at 0 cost.

```
from pulp import *

# Define the problem
prob = LpProblem("Production Switches", LpMinimize)

# Define the variables
articles = ['Article1', 'Article2', 'Article3']
timeslots=list(range(10))
switches = LpVariable.dicts("Switch", [(t,a1, a2) for t in timeslots for a1 in articles for a2 in articles], cat='Binary')

# We *have to* switch every time exactly once
for t in timeslots:
    prob += lpSum([switches[(t, a1, a2)] for a1 in articles for a2 in articles]) == 1

# enforce switching only from previously switched articles
for t in timeslots[1:]:
    for a2 in articles:
        prob += lpSum([switches[(t - 1, a1, a2)] for a1 in articles]) == lpSum([switches[(t, a2, a3)] for a3 in articles])

# Can only produce up to 4 times the same article
max_production=4
for a1 in articles:
    prob += lpSum([switches[(t, a1, a2)] for t in timeslots for a2 in articles]) <= max_production
# Define the cost of switching
switch_cost = {
    ('Article1', 'Article1'): 0,  
    ('Article2', 'Article2'): 0, 
    ('Article3', 'Article3'): 0, 
    ('Article1', 'Article2'): 10,  
    ('Article1', 'Article3'): 15,  
    ('Article2', 'Article1'): 12,  
    ('Article2', 'Article3'): 8,   
    ('Article3', 'Article1'): 20,  
    ('Article3', 'Article2'): 18   
}

# Define the total cost of switching
total_switch_cost = lpSum([switch_cost[(a1, a2)] * switches[(t,a1, a2)] for a1 in articles for a2 in articles for t in timeslots])

# set that as objective
prob += total_switch_cost

prob.solve()

print("Optimal Switches:")
for t in timeslots:
    for a1 in articles:
        for a2 in articles:
            if switches[(t,a1, a2)].varValue == 1:
                print(f"{a1} -> {a2}")

print("Total Switch Cost:", value(total_switch_cost))
```

This produces:

```
Article1 -> Article1
Article1 -> Article1
Article1 -> Article1
Article1 -> Article2
Article2 -> Article2
Article2 -> Article3
Article3 -> Article3
Article3 -> Article3
Article3 -> Article3
Article3 -> Article3
Total Switch Cost: 18.0
```